# How to automatically Import, Name and Export multiple images?

Tags: files-and-directories

I have a directory (`myDataDir`) full of images (`"myImage1.tif"`, `"myImage2.tif"`, ...), and I have a function (let's call it `myProcessingFunction[myImage]` that gives as output `myPartList` a list of images that are parts of the original source image.

What I want to do is:

1. Import all the images in myDir one at the time
2. Run `myProcessingFunction` on each image
3. Save each output image contained in `myPartList` as `"myImageN_partP.tif"` where `myImageN` is the name of the input file and `P` is the Pth component of `myPartList` generated for that file.

Comment: somewhere should be better example for duplicate, meanwhile: [link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31993/5478)

Comment: I think this is a better duplicate than the ones linked: [(1122)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1122/121)

Comment: Sorry for the duplicates and thanks for the links!